# Javassist constant pool

Tags: java, javassist

**Question 1:** How would I change the signatures of entries within the `ConstPool`? For example, lets say I had a `methodref` to a method with a signature "`()Ljava.util.Collection;`". How can I change that to say, "`()I`"?

I want to do this because when a release comes out for an API, and a dependency on the updated API still uses the old method, I want to change the signature used, making sure that the dependent application implements this safely.

**Question 2:** How can I iterate through the `LongVector` of constant pool entries, without having to use reflection every single step of the way? Since `LongVector` is package private, `ConstInfo` is package private, and I would have to use reflection to get all the method return types, in a loop too.

This will be used in tandem with problem number 1 to iterate through the constant pool and modify the signatures and store their information in a class lookup.

Comment: The two questions seem unrelated. Please split them into two questions.

Comment: Should I elaborate more on how I will use them *together*?

Comment: Especially show us some code and describe what you expect it to do, what it does, and any error you get.

Comment: You really really really don't want to do this, and I doubt that the Java bytecode verifier will let you. Evolve your API in a backwards-compatible way like everybody else (!) does.

Comment: @EJP Honestly, I think it's really creepy how you follow every question of mine, but okay. A bytecode verifier cannot predict runtime conditions, therefore, I don't believe this will happen. Besides that, I renamed a few of my classes that moved out of experimental to production ready, and I have already thought about that...

Comment: Soundw like the worst idea of the day, but still somehow interesting if you could do that :D

Comment: @ThomasUhrig I *can* do it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use reflection - there's no other way to access the ConstInfo. The signatures can be found in the name and type index of the MethodRef.

2) Use reflection - there's also no other way to access the elements of the LongVector. Get the LongVector, get the elements at each index per size (both which can be accessed using reflection - LongVector simply had to also be package-local), and pass them to question 1.

Thanks for all the help!